# adding only the parent class of button

Tags: javascript

How can I make this when I clicked the 1st button the class `display` will add on the main parent `ul`, however if I clicked the second button the 1st main parent `ul` will removed the `display` class and will add it on the 2nd main parent - it's just removing and adding class base on parent class.

```js
const btn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn")

for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
    let btnParent = e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement
    if(btnParent.classList.contains("display")) {
      btnParent.classList.remove("display")
    } else{
      btnParent.classList.add("display")
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.btn {
  background: yellow;
}
.ul {
  transition: .33s ease all;
}
.ul.display {
 background:green ;
}
```

```html
<div class="ul">
  <div class="li">
    <div class="li a">List Link</div>
    <div class="li a">List Link</div>
    <div class="li a">List Link</div>
    <div class="btn">Click me</div>
  </div>  
</div>
<br>
<div class="ul">
  <div class="li">
    <div class="li a">List Link</div>
    <div class="li a">List Link</div>
    <div class="li a">List Link</div>
  </div>  
</div>
<br>
<div class="ul">
  <div class="li">
    <div class="li a">List Link</div>
    <div class="li a">List Link</div>
    <div class="li a">List Link</div>
    <div class="btn">Click me</div>
  </div>  
</div>

<div class="ul">
  <div class="li">
    <div class="li a">List Link</div>
    <div class="li a">List Link</div>
    <div class="li a">List Link</div>
    <div class="btn">Click me</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not need to make the selection disappear when you click on the same element again, you can add:

```
const uls = document.querySelectorAll('.ul');
```

And something like this inside:

```
uls.forEach(item => {
    item.classList.remove('display');
});
```

The result will be like this:

```
const uls = document.querySelectorAll('.ul');
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        let btnParent = e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement;
        uls.forEach(item => {
            item.classList.remove('display');
        });
        btnParent.classList.toggle("display");
    })
}
```

Hope this helps!
Regards,